# Dynamics CRM 365 plugin to external SQL Server

Tags: wcf, plugins, dynamics-crm, integration, dynamics-crm-365

Currently we are using plugins to integrate records for Dynamics CRM 2011 (on premise) to back office (SQL Server) using WCF as a bridge. This process is same for insert and update. (Plugin > WCF > stored procedure)

However, we are due to upgrade to Dynamics CRM 365 on Azure and wondering if there are any better (new tech!) ways to do the same process?

I would really appreciate if you can share your experience with similar CRM to Back Office sync.

Answer (score 0):

We are using (and I recommend) [Data Export service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744592.aspx)

> Data Export is an add-on service made available as a Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) solution that adds the ability to replicate Dynamics 365 (online) data to a Microsoft Azure SQL Database store in a customer-owned Microsoft Azure subscription. The supported target destinations are Microsoft Azure SQL Database and Microsoft Azure SQL Server on Microsoft Azure virtual machines. Data Export intelligently synchronizes the entire Dynamics 365 schema and data initially and thereafter synchronizes on a continuous basis as changes occur (delta changes) in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) system.

Probably the easiest/cleanest way. Just a Managed solution import, enabling Change tracking for Entities, setup Azure SQL & Key vault, friendly Profile setup & sync issues troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for that but this will create a copy of CRM db and scheme. I am syncing data to our back office system hence this sync will involved heavy amount of transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF services is available in the internet I do not see any reason to change the working integration (unless you really want to get rid of good, old WCF :)).

If it is intranet-only app you will probably need to use some other integration patterns and technologies. For example: service bus, web jobs, app logic, etc.

All of them may work perfecly well, however there are many different conditions that need to be considered during decission process.